# Process input interface stop responding when virtual memory usage reach to 256gb

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets, memory

I want to know that multithread application process which spawn few core threads to process request receive on TCP socket, udp socket or serial interface, stop responding on these interfaces when virtual memory size reach to 256gb.

This is happening every time run binary for long duration.

Top command output-

```
top - 11:14:15 up 3 days,  5:47,  8 users,  load average: 0.43, 0.47, 0.47
Threads:   9 total,   0 running,   9 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.5 us, 15.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 83.7 id,  0.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   3972884 total,  2745296 used,  1227588 free,   117920 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free,  1344768 cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
10745 root      20   0  256g 529m 2348 S  14.6 13.6  67:28.74 obcs
10371 root      20   0  256g 529m 2348 S   0.0 13.6   0:01.32 obcs
10373 root      20   0  256g 529m 2348 S   0.0 13.6   1:21.92 obcs
10707 root      20   0  256g 529m 2348 S   0.0 13.6   0:00.00 obcs
10740 root      20   0  256g 529m 2348 S   0.0 13.6   0:00.04 obcs
10741 root      20   0  256g 529m 2348 S   0.0 13.6   0:00.86 obcs
10742 root      20   0  256g 529m 2348 S   0.0 13.6   0:17.00 obcs
10743 root      20   0  256g 529m 2348 S   0.0 13.6   0:00.00 obcs
10744 root      20   0  256g 529m 2348 S   0.0 13.6   0:01.26 obcs
```

also once there is pthread create failure with error - [Cannot allocate memory] , which is use to process any request & after that no new thread create request seen in logs.

OS version - Debian 3.16.7-ckt4-3~bpo70+1 (2015-02-12) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Is this memory leak issue, memory consumption is increasing continuously on the top command output.

```
root@Moxa:~# cat /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
0

root@Moxa:~# cat /proc/5518/maps
00400000-0046c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 276281                             /opt/obcs/bin/obcs
0066b000-0066c000 r--p 0006b000 08:01 276281                             /opt/obcs/bin/obcs
0066c000-0066e000 rw-p 0006c000 08:01 276281                             /opt/obcs/bin/obcs
0066e000-00672000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
015de000-0161f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fa2af35a000-7fa2af35b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7fa2af35b000-7fa2afb5b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

.......huge number of entry
```

or is this kernel configuration setting issue?

for example if i run the following source-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


void *thread_func(void *arg);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int s,i=0;
  void *res;
  pthread_t t1[100];

  printf("In Main()\n");
  sleep(20);
  while (i < 100) {
    s = pthread_create(&t1[i], NULL, thread_func, "Hello World\n");

    if (s != 0)
      printf("Err\n");


    usleep (600000);

    i++;
  }
 i=0;
 while (i < 100) {
   //s = pthread_detach(t1);
   s = pthread_join(t1[i],NULL);
   if (s != 0)
     printf("Err\n");
   i++;
 }
  sleep (60);
  return 0;
}

void *thread_func(void *arg)
{
  char *s = (char *)arg;
  char *ptr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*2048);
  memset(ptr,'s',2048);
  printf("%s", s);

  sleep(5);
/* printf("%s",ptr); */
  free(ptr);
  pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Then top command output at 4 different time when binary is executing-

```
top - 09:05:00 up 167 days, 16:22,  4 users,  load average: 0.02, 0.03, 0.05
Tasks:   1 total,   0 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.9%us,  0.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 98.2%id,  0.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1017128k total,   750380k used,   266748k free,   145164k buffers
Swap:  1046524k total,    18544k used,  1027980k free,   408268k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
22710 root      20   0  6328  380  296 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 a.out


top - 09:05:51 up 167 days, 16:23,  4 users,  load average: 0.01, 0.03, 0.05
Cpu(s):  0.3%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 98.0%id,  1.3%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1017128k total,   751436k used,   265692k free,   145236k buffers
Swap:  1046524k total,    18544k used,  1027980k free,   408256k cached

22710 root      20   0 1104m 1144  592 S  0.3  0.1   0:00.01 a.out
22895 root      20   0 1104m 1144  592 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 a.out
22898 root      20   0 1104m 1144  592 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 a.out
22901 root      20   0 1104m 1144  592 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 a.out
22902 root      20   0 1104m 1144  592 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 a.out
22905 root      20   0 1104m 1144  592 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 a.out
22906 root      20   0 1104m 1144  592 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 a.out
22909 root      20   0 1104m 1144  592 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 a.out
22912 root      20   0 1104m 1144  592 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 a.out


top - 09:06:06 up 167 days, 16:23,  4 users,  load average: 0.01, 0.03, 0.05
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Swap:  1046524k total,    18544k used,  1027980k free,   408272k cached

22710 root      20   0 1304m 1416  592 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.01 a.out
22950 root      20   0 1304m 1416  592 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 a.out
22953 root      20   0 1304m 1416  592 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 a.out
22954 root      20   0 1304m 1416  592 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 a.out
22957 root      20   0 1304m 1416  592 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 a.out
22960 root      20   0 1304m 1416  592 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 a.out
22961 root      20   0 1304m 1416  592 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 a.out
22964 root      20   0 1304m 1416  592 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 a.out
22965 root      20   0 1304m 1416  592 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 a.out


top - 09:06:09 up 167 days, 16:23,  4 users,  load average: 0.01, 0.03, 0.05
Tasks:   6 total,   0 running,   6 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.7%us,  0.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 97.7%id,  1.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1017128k total,   751048k used,   266080k free,   145260k buffers
Swap:  1046524k total,    18544k used,  1027980k free,   408268k cached

22710 root      20   0  592m  872  592 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.01 a.out
22961 root      20   0  592m  872  592 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 a.out
22964 root      20   0  592m  872  592 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 a.out
22965 root      20   0  592m  872  592 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 a.out
22968 root      20   0  592m  872  592 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 a.out
22971 root      20   0  592m  872  592 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 a.out


top - 09:06:12 up 167 days, 16:23,  4 users,  load average: 0.01, 0.03, 0.05
Tasks:   1 total,   0 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1017128k total,   750884k used,   266244k free,   145260k buffers
Swap:  1046524k total,    18544k used,  1027980k free,   408276k cached

22710 root      20   0  552m  836  592 S  0.3  0.1   0:00.02 a.out
```

when only main thread was only running at start that time virtual, resident memory consumption 6328 & 380 & then child thread are start execution so virtual & resident memory increase again but when all threads have finish its execution then virtual & resident memory consumption should be near 6328 & 380 but it is 552m  836.

Comment: `[Cannot allocate memory]`  You are obviously not freeing allocated memory and have exhausted all resources available to you.  We'll need to see the code before it can be established to be a design issue, leak or other...

Comment: "Is this memory leak issue"..."when virtual memory size reach to 256gb". You have to ask?

Comment: Obviously its a memory leak issue.

Comment: You have  4GB of physical mmeory, and you have n process using 256Gb of virtual memory each. I wonder how the whole machine copes with it.

Comment: So you run out of virtual address space, or hit some other limitation, no more threads can be created by your process, and things naturally don't work. Yes you have a leak somewhere, perhaps you don't properly dispose the threads you're creating, or don't control the amount of threads you create in the first place.

Comment: @nos we have run the valgrind  tool but did not find any memory leak still i   also think that there may be some design issue or threads are not disposed properly. we also found that one thread was disposed without releasing memory because other  process kill that thread. after fixing such issue same problem occur.

Comment: @user1868132 Well, then you need to either show some code, or do some debugging. A common mistake though is to not dispose of threads. Remember that some internal resources held by a thread are NOT released when that thread exits unless either  1. The thread is a detached thread. 2. You call pthread_join() on that thread. So make sure you're doing one of those 2.

Comment: @nos this time we are sure that there is no memory leak, as we have write wrapper over malloc & free also. Now i have tried a small example to test pthread behavior. this example showing the same behavior which we are facing in our binary. adding example source code & top command output.

Comment: Your test program has 100 threads going (your code does not completely destroy the threads (by using pthread_join) until your 1. loop is done) leaving you with the footprint of 100 threads, even if those threads have exited.  A common stack size on linux for a thread is 10 MB, so you'll have around 1GB of virtual memory just for the stack of those 100 threads when your loop is done. If you did a pthread_join() right after your `usleep(600000);`, things would look different. 10MB stack for a thread is _very_ large, you could set the stack size to e.g. just 100KB, to mitigate this too.

Comment: @nos even if i am all the child thread detachable, top command output shown VIRT - 6328k & RES - 384k in the start & 552m & 576k in the end.

Comment: @user1868132 Is that the commented out line with pthread_detach ? You will still have allocated the resources of 100 threads concurrently, even if many of those have exited. Even if the virtual memory does not decrease further once you're done with your 2. loop doing either pthread_detach() or pthread_join (not both, just one of those) , there will NOT be  problem, that virtual memory can be reused. If you did  not call pthread_join() or pthread_detach() there WILL be a problem, since that virtual memory could not be reused later on.

Comment: @nos  i think this is problem of collect fragmented memory after pthread_exit. I have done following changes in the source- int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("In Main()\n");
  sleep(20);
  while (i < 100) {
    s = pthread_create(&t1[i], NULL, thread_func, "Hello World\n");

    s = pthread_detach(t1[i]);
    usleep (600000);
    i++;
  }
sleep (60);
}

Comment: That makes the threads release it's memory immediately when it extis, so sure you won't be holding on to the ressources of all 100 threads at the same time in that case. There's not an issue with memory fragmentation if you're on a 64 bit machine with your example though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i got the solution.
to make thread detachable, we should use pthread_attr_setdetachstate() function to set attribute PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED before thread creation instead of using pthread_detach() function after thread creation.

solution -

```
rc = pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
rc = pthread_create(&thread1, &attr, testFunction, NULL);
```

instead of -

```
 s = pthread_create(&t1[i], NULL, thread_func, "Hello World\n");
 s = pthread_detach(t1[i]);
```

this solution works for me.Thanks for the discussion.